# signal = SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0xc)) Android Native Debugging in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-debug

What is the cause of this error :

```
SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0xc))
```

while debugging the Android Native code. It occurs when I am trying to step into (F7) a native function from the Android Java code?

Debugging is chosen as "Dual" and I have already referred the symbol directories as =>libs\armeabi in the Debugger Tab's Symbol Directories TAB.

The project has been built using the ndk build method(instead of CMAKE)

below is the gradle file snippet :

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'path to Android.mk'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add complete logs showing offset in the library.